# how to change the title of an active PR on github

Tags: github

How to change the title of an active pull request (PR).
The edit allows editing description and not title, How do I change the title of the PR if that PR has not been merged yet.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to click on the PR and update the title as shown below, see that I have just updated the title of an active PR.

[image]